# Как проверить сессии на подлинность?

Tags: node.js, сессия, express

Только взялся за сессии.
Использую `express-sessions`.
Вот хранится sid на клиенте. Через post приходят данные с формы для авторизации. Потом по данным ищутся в БД ищется пользователь с таким логином, если найдет то сохраняется `req.session.save()`.
Но гложит вопрос, если как-то будет подмена сессии, то как проверить. Была идея, чтобы на каждый запрос сайту проверять есть ли такая сессия в хранилище.
На мой взгляд простая проверка `if(req.session.sid)` не очень хорошая идея. Здесь просто проверка наличия сессии, но не ее подлинности, а каждый раз подключаться к БД, сравнивать - затратно.

Но вопрос, может есть более простые и быстрые методы? Может есть какие-то встроенные механизмы?

Comment: Механизм http сессий не предполагает проверки подлинности. Тут нет зависимости от языка/фреймворка.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить сессию на подлинность нужно всего лишь для куки генерить 
такой же секрет как и у сессии или дела сессии его не давать, а дать только 
кукисам и так ясно что они по кукам живут, так вот потом проверяешь саму куку на подлинность если она была изменена, то удали сессию

```
 app.use(cookie('AZINO777'))
 app.use(session({
  name: 'SSID',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new sequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize
  }),
  cookie: {
    signed: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    // secure: true
  }
}))
```

А вот и проверка куку на подлинность

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('SIGNED', req.signedCookies['SSID'])
  if (!req.signedCookies['SSID']) {
    req.session.destroy()
    res.send('СЕССИЯ БЫЛА ПОДМЕНЕНА')
  }
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне известно, то встроенных механизмов проверки нет.

Предлагаю использовать HTTPS, не передавать пароли в открытом виде, добавить какой-либо ключ к сессии в которой удачно прошла авторизация и дополнительно проверять его наличие.

Если вам и этого мало, то смотреть в сторону криптопровайдеров (к прим. Крипто Про) и плагинов для браузера.